# How to make a JSON array inside an array

Tags: javascript, database, json, local-storage

first post ever here

I'm trying to replicate this sort of JSON object so that I can store it inside localStorage with stringify:

I want to be able to create a new noteState inside of history whenever an event is caught but do not know necessarily how to go about doing so..

```
var history = {
    "noteState1": [
        {created: new Date(),
        modified: new Date(),
        left: "100",
        top: "200",
        text: "hello"},

        {created: new Date(),
        modified: new Date(),
        left: "150",
        top: "250",
        text: "new"},

        {created: new Date(),
        modified: new Date(),
        left: "200",
        top: "300",
        text: "world"}
    ], 
    "noteState2": [
        {created: new Date(),
        modified: new Date(),
        left: "100",
        top: "200",
        text: "hello"},

        {created: new Date(),
        modified: new Date(),
        left: "150",
        top: "250",
        text: "new"},

        {created: new Date(),
        modified: new Date(),
        left: "200",
        top: "300",
        text: "world"}
    ]
}
```

how can i create a new member with a single array inside history?

Comment: look at the JSON.parse and JSON.stringify methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't modify the json string - that's too risky. Instead you convert it back to a native javascript array/object, use the regular array push/pop type operators on it, then convert back to a json string.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just maintain your history as an array of objects and then add a new noteState? When you want to store you're array, simply insert each of the noteStates in the history array into a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

before you do anything, convert those json strings to objects. By doing that, you can easily just add namespaces to history like this:

```
history.noteStateX = { x:1,y:2 };
```

and now history has that property as well as the others.